# Translation of "There is nothing to delete"

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

How can I translate the following sentence into german?
"There is nothing to delete".

What is correct?

> Es ist nichts zu löschen.

or

> Es gibt nichts zu löschen

Comment: Any research done on your own?

Comment: *Nothing* is *nichts* in German. To the extend there's a noun *das Nichts* which means *the nothing*.

Answer (score 3):

Both examples are (almost) correct:

> Es ist nichts zu löschen.

This is perfectly fine, although it sound more like you're trying to say that nothing *requires* deletion, even though there is something that you could delete.

If you, however, want to say that there simply *is* nothing to delete, the following is better:

> Es gibt nicht**s** zu löschen.

Note the "s" of "nichts" - the example from your question missed that (whether by accident or lack of knowledge, I don't know). I edited the question though, so once it's accepted, just ignore this paragraph :)
(Unless you *didn't* lack the "s" by accident only, of course!)